# Example of Propagation in spring data JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am trying to understand the propagation attribute of @Transactional annotation in Spring Data JPA. I have read enough theory. But I do not understand(nor can I find anywhere on internet) the real-life scenario where I need to use the **PROPAGATION_REQUIRED** in place of **PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW**. I understand the theory that PROPAGATION_REQUIRED can utilize the existing transaction and PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW will start a new transaction each time. But I could not understand two things -

1. How does it matter to me as a programmer? or in which used cases one is preferred over other?
2. Is the "TRANSACTION" we are talking about is a spring transaction or a database transaction

Answer (score -1):

In Spring, if a method that is annotated with @Transactional calls another method annotated with @Transactional, the transaction is started at the beginning of the first method and commited after the second method is finished.

Requiring a new transaction can be helpful, if you have a sequence of methods that are transactional but you want to commit a transaction half way through the sequence.
Or maybe you have a method that should always open it's own transaction and you want to make sure it does so, even if it is called by another transactional method.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).